# ficheros de acceso directo Java

Tags: java

Lo que necesito es saber por qué cuando introduzco un registro para leer me salta la excepcion `EOF` que dice que no hay más registros en el archivo. Yo tengo creado en el código que cada registro que tenga una longitud de 44 bytes para ir directamente a un registro. Entonces quería saber cuál es mi fallo.. Le digo que quiero ir al registro 1 y me salta la excepción. ¿Me podéis hacer un fichero de ejemplo, o decirme dónde está el fallo?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Principal{
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int longRegistro, n, id;
        double salario;
        String apellido;
        Scanner lectura = new Scanner (System.in);
        RandomAccessFile entrada = null;
        String nombreFichero;
        try {
            System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del fichero");
            nombreFichero = lectura.next();
            entrada = new RandomAccessFile(nombreFichero, "r");
            System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de registro a leer");
            n = lectura.nextInt();
            longRegistro = 44; //4 bytes (int), 30(String)+2 UTF, 8(double)
            entrada.seek((n - 1) * longRegistro);
            id = entrada.readInt();
            apellido = entrada.readUTF();
            salario = entrada.readDouble();
            System.out.printf("%d %s %.2f\n", id, apellido, salario);
        }
        catch (EOFException e) {
            System.out.println("\nHa llegado al final del fichero. "    +   "El numero de registro no existe.");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("El fichero especificado no existe");
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Excepcion de entrada/salida:" +
            e.toString());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
        try {
            entrada.close();
        }
        catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println("No se ha podido cerrar el fichero" +io.toString());
            System.out.println(io.getMessage());
        }
       } // Fin finally
    } // Fin método main
}
```

Comment: Por favor, indica un ejemplo de contenido de fichero que quieres leer.

Comment: 1 Gabriel 1000.5(este sería un ejemplo así con más registros un int String double)

Comment: para empezar, cada valor en el fichero tiene que tener la longitud exacta en bytes que especificas: 0001 Gabriel_asdfghjklzxcvbnmqwerty 1000.500

Comment: Lo he puesto como me has dicho, y ahora me lee datos pero los unico que me lee son unos numeros muy largos, porque es eso? no me lee los datos

Comment: El problema es que lo que obtienes es el código de cada dígito, en vez de un cero obtienes su valor en ascii. Por favor, mira bien en la documentación que hay en oracle, allí lo explica bien.

Answer (score 1):

Viendo que aún no tienes respuesta y basandome en la conversación de los comentarios, te voy a proponer una manera mucho mas sencilla y corta de leer **y parsear** los datos de un fichero modelo como el que propones:

**FICHERO: (`datos.txt`)**

```
1 Gabriel 10.5
2 Jordi 340.23
3 Javi 432
```

**Principal.java** (he puesto la opcion de leer todo el fichero para mostrarte otra manera de leer)

```
private static final String FOLDER  = "D:\\Users\\VEMIJCS\\_1\\";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("nombre fichero ");
    String file = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("fila a leer (0 todas) ");
    int row = in.nextInt(); 
    in.close();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FOLDER + file)); 
    String line = "";

    // mostramos todo el fichero
    if (row == 0) {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            print(line);
        }
    } else {
        // leemos hasta la linea que nos han pedido
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) { 
            line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null) { 
                System.out.println("no existe la linea numero " + row);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        // e imprimimos
        print(line);
    }
    reader.close();
}

private static void print(String line) {
    int numero      = Integer.parseInt(line.trim().split(" ")[0]);
    String nombre   = line.trim().split(" ")[1];
    double valor    = Double.parseDouble(line.trim().split(" ")[2]);

    System.out.println(nombre.toUpperCase() + " ocupa la linea numero: " + numero + " y tiene un valor de " + valor);

}
```

---

**SALIDA PARA NUMERO DE LINEA VALIDO**

```
nombre fichero datos.txt
fila a leer (0 todas) 2
JORDI ocupa la linea numero: 2 y tiene un valor de 340.23
```

**SALIDA PARA NUMERO DE LINEA == 0**

```
nombre fichero datos.txt
fila a leer (0 todas) 0
GABRIEL ocupa la linea numero: 1 y tiene un valor de 10.5
JORDI ocupa la linea numero: 2 y tiene un valor de 340.23
JAVI ocupa la linea numero: 3 y tiene un valor de 432.0
```

**SALIDA PARA NUMERO DE LINEA NO VALIDO**

```
nombre fichero datos.txt
fila a leer (0 todas) 9
no existe la linea numero 9
```

---

**NOTAS**

- Imports necesarios:

  ```
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.FileReader;
  import java.util.Scanner;
  ```
- No he realizado control de excepciones para parsear los datos pero no olvides implementarlo por si los datos del fichero no son correctos.
- El fichero debe estar situado en el directorio `FOLDER` correspondiente.
- Si tienes alguna duda, [sílbame](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QO7KYyDSkXA) `:)`.